# Method with if statement with syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing some Ruby excercises. My goal is to create a method which reproduces the first and last number of an array.

My way of thinking was:

```
#create array
a = [1,2,3,4]
#create method
def lastFirst
   return a[0,3]
end
#call the method with an array
lastFirst(a)
```

But this produces `[1,2,3]` instead of what I want, which is `(1,3)`.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a[0,3]
```

means get 3 elements starting from offset 0.

Try this:

```
def lastFirst(a)
  [a.first, a.last]
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Write it using the [`Array#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-values_at) method:

```
#create array
a = [1,2,3,4]
#create method
def last_first(a)
  a.values_at(0, -1)
end
#call the method
last_first(a) # => [1, 4]
```